# datagridview and row unsharing

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I've encountered a performance issue with the C# DataGridView control, which appears to be the result of the unsharing of a large number of rows. The DataGridView is bound to a bindingsource, which is, in turn, bound to a dataview. I've gone through the laundry list of dos and don'ts from the MSDN info (not using rows.count() etc), but I just can't get it to play the game.

Even if I start with a brand new DataGridView control, on a fresh form, and bind it to a bindingsource that has a basic test table as its source, just showing the form seems to cause all of the displayed rows to become unshared. Then, every single row I select causes that row to become unshared. I'm wondering if I'm wasting my time trying to prevent this?

In my actual DataGridView control, it's necessary for me to have at least one column that is not visible, which contains ID values. It's also necessary for me to search all the values in this column for a matching ID. It would appear that, as soon as I attempt to iterate through the values to find a match, this is causing every single row to become unshared. Is there a way to do this that does *not* cause all the rows to become unshared as I search?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "unshared"

Comment: As per the information contained in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I never read any of that, even back in .NET 2.0 days. Based on the part I read, displaying such a form should not cause the rows to become unshared. Their data should still be stored external to the control, so they should still share most of the row instances. I think you're right that searching the grid yourself is causing your problem. How about not searching the grid, but instead searching the data that is bound to the grid?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to iterate over the rows? Are you using the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.item.aspx) property, or the [`SharedRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.sharedrow.aspx) method?

Comment: I thought as much John. The issue is that I need to select the matching row after I find the one with the ID I'm looking for, so I'm not sure if there's an acceptable solution that doesn't involve actually looking through the ID column. The resultant increase in consumed memory is negligible after the rows become unshared, but it's the delay while it unshares all 30K+ rows I was trying to avoid. It's only a problem the first time it does it though, so maybe that's just how it has to be. Thanks for the suggestions though :)